# AWS Lamda api not working from browser showing syntax error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a simple method to update the Dynamotable item. If I hardcoded the value in lambda function and test it from lamda its working absolutely fine but the problem is when I am trying to add values from the event it's showing some syntax error.

Here is my lamda function

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const params = {
    TableName: "Would-You-Rather",
    Key:{
        "QuestionID": event.QuestionID,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set Would = :w, Rather = :r, wouldClick = :wC, ratherClick = :rC",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":w": event.Would,
        ":r": event.Rather,
        ":wC": event.wouldClick,
        ":rC": event.ratherClick
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};

console.log("Updating the item...");
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});

};
```

This is my test event i am testing from lamda

```
{
  "Would": "Soap",
  "Rather": "Oil",
  "wouldClick": "50",
  "ratherClick": "13",
  "QuestionID": "16563fa7-e833-445f-a76b-a9fbaab3a301"
}
```

And its working fine but when i try to run from codepen its showing syntax error here is my code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', 'https://iv9803zj9d.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Development/would-you-rather');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'allow');

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({Would: Coffe,Rather: Tea, wouldClick: 15, ratherClick: 13, QuestionID: 16563fa7-e833-445f-a76b-a9fbaab3a301}));
```

Its showing this error

```
level: "ERROR"
line: -6
message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'"
type: "js"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your value in string quotes. As the above answer you need to add string quotes not only in `QuestionID` But also with `Would` and `Rather` values.

Like this

```
{Would: "Coffe",Rather: "Tea", wouldClick: 15, ratherClick: 13, QuestionID: "16563fa7-e833-445f-a76b-a9fbaab3a301"}
```

So your whole code look like this If have tested and its working :)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', 'https://iv9803zj9d.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Development/would-you-rather');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'allow');

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({Would: "Coffe",Rather: "Tea", wouldClick: 15, ratherClick: 13, QuestionID: "16563fa7-e833-445f-a76b-a9fbaab3a301"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GUID for `QuestionID` should have string quotes around it, like so:

```
QuestionID: "16563fa7-e833-445f-a76b-a9fbaab3a301"
```